# How does it works the "HTTP 101 Protocols Switching" in a client server communication?

Tags: firefox, nginx, webserver, http

I'm developing a web site that is served by the web server `NGINX` installed on a Linux platform. One of the service provided by the web site is base on a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) backend server.

To be more specific the NGINX configuration establishes that when NGINX receive from the client a request of the type:

```
GET /websockify HTTP/1.1
```

the request is redirected (proxied) to the *WebSocket backend server*. These configuration is achived by the following block of settings:

```
location /websockify {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Sniffing by **Wireshark** I have seen that the client sends an HTTP request with the following 2 header in the HTTP request:

```
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
```

and NGINX sends an HTTP response of the type:

```
101 Swiching Protocols
```

After that (in base of Wireshark info) the communication switches from HTTP to a different protocol called *WebSocket* that I don't know.

Sometimes my Firefox browser, that in this context work obviously as a client, stops work and is not able to establish a connection with the WebSocket backend server.

To be sure that there are not present some errors in the web site configuration I would like to ask: the Protocols Switching is implemented by the browser? After this switching the browser starts to send data in a different manner than before the switching?

All other information about this topic are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebSocket wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) seems to have a good overview, and, further down the page, a description of the handshake that the client and server code use to switch their protocol from HTTP to WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks. If you have some other info relative to your direct experience with WebSocket I will happy to receive that.